# How to Refresh data in ng-Repeat after Delete Or Update Records

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am new in angularJs.. I have One Query How to refresh data in ng-Repeat

My View Look Like This :

[image: My view]

Now, I Press the Delete Button Event then the Record Not Remove From Grid ...

[image: View Description]

```
$scope.Deletepovider = function (ProviderListId) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
        var getmsg = AdminService.DeleteProviderDetail(ProviderListId, '/Admin/Delete', $scope.onDeleteCompleted, $scope.onDeleteError);
        return true;
    } else {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
$scope.onDeleteCompleted = function (response, status) {}
$scope.onDeleteError = function (response, status) {}
```

Comment: You probably not removing the `provider` from the collection, can you add your JS code as well?

Comment: This is my Js Code..    $scope.Deletepovider = function (ProviderListId) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
            var getmsg = AdminService.DeleteProviderDetail(ProviderListId, '/Admin/Delete', $scope.onDeleteCompleted, $scope.onDeleteError);           
            return true;
        }
        else {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;

        }

    }
    $scope.onDeleteCompleted = function (response, status) {            
    }
    $scope.onDeleteError = function (response, status) {
    }

Comment: Please, edit your question and add code there. But from what I can see you don't update the collection, you just delete the record through `AdminService`. What you should do is to update `$scope.filteredUsedRoles` when the delete is succefull

Comment: I Can't Add there Because my reputation is below 10 show, i put only two images...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, in general, you don't want to "refresh" your list after performing an operation like this. Rather, you want to manage the list it's bound to. Consider something like this:

```
$scope.Deletepovider = function (ProviderListId)
{
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?'))
  {
    var getmsg = AdminService.DeleteProviderDetail(
      ProviderListId,
      '/Admin/Delete',
      function () {
        // remove the provider from the list the ng-repeat is bound to
        // you could use anything like lodash or underscore to find the
        // provider by ID (referencing ProviderListId above)
      },
      function(err) {

      });
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** take notice to the comments I added in the success callback. That's your solution.

Comment: @RaviShah it appears you removed this as the answer; what happened? You said it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes This way you can refresh your grid after deleting records.

```
$scope.delete = function () {
    var promiseDeleteStudent = SPACRUDService.delete(ShareData.value);

    promiseDeleteStudent.then(function (pl) {
        $location.path("/showstudents");  /*write your lists method */
    },
          function (errorPl) {
              $scope.error = 'failure loading Student', errorPl;
          });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So after checking the code provided it seems that you need to update your code a bit to actually update the collection after successfully deleting it or you can remove record directly from the collection before passing to the `DeleteProvider`

```
$scope.Deletepovider = function (ProviderListId) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
        var getmsg = AdminService.DeleteProviderDetail(ProviderListId, '/Admin/Delete', $scope.onDeleteCompleted, $scope.onDeleteError);
        return true;
    } else {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
$scope.onDeleteCompleted = function (response, status) {
  $scope.filteredUserRoles = //update the data through service or method
}
$scope.onDeleteError = function (response, status) {}
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for Reply.. I Tried this solution in js side when i print console log  that record deleted but in that time grid display this Record Grid not refresh at that time.. when i refresh Page That time it's work..